# How to change cursor and pointer color in Huawei P9 Lite

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles, android-textinputlayout, huawei-mobile-services

Create project by using **Login Activity** template with **minimum SDK API 14** from Android Studio, then customize `colorAccent` as pink color in **styles.xml**:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item><!-- pink color -->

</style>
```

**LG Nexus 5X** able to take effect (Tested with Marshmallow and Nougat):
[image]

But no effect in **Huawei P9 Lite** (Marshmallow):
[image]

What should i do to make cursor+pointer color portable ?

Note that `colorControlActivated` has the same problem, not only `colorAccent`.

**[UPDATE]**

Tested with **Xiaomi Mi 3** and no such problem. `android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/fb"` has the same behaviour for this 3 devices (i.e. only **Huawei P9 Lite** not working).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Define a drawable resource : `cursor_green.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/green"/>
<size android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

And then set it to `EditText` using

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_green"
```

Comment: 1. This only able to change cursor(vertical line) color, not including pointer(water shape) color. 2. Nevertheless, Huawei P9 Lite still not able to take effect even cursor color with your code, but LG Nexus 5X no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to EditText. It helps me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I not able to reproduce it to test your answer, it seems like Huawei P9 Lite patched the bug.